# How to download an epub file locally to our iPhone?

Tags: iphone, epub

I want to download an epub file in to my app locally by passing the url of the file:

http://www.jedisaber.com/eBooks/books/sample.epub

Clicking this url should download an epub. How can I get it to download to my app?

I tried using  NSData but it didn't work. I also tried copying the file to my document directory but it also didn't work. Can anybody tell me how can I do this in Objective-C?

Any help code would be appreciated!

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hi , Do you find a solution for the above problem.If Yes than please write to me in the following link.Thanks in Advance. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16416640/how-to-download-epub-format-file-from-url-to-document-directory-in-iphone

Answer (score 2):

EPUB is a ZIP format, you can use any Binary Stream Downloading method and save the file first as a binary file on iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

AS arcon Mentioned EPUB is a ZIP format,  You have to Unzip the file 
to unzip the file & save the documents directory to ur machine:
ZipArchive* za = [[ZipArchive alloc] init];
    if( [za UnzipOpenFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Help" ofType:@"epub"]] ){

```
    NSString *strPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/UnzippedEpub",[self applicationDocumentsDirectory]];

    //Delete all the previous files
    NSFileManager *filemanager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
    if ([filemanager fileExistsAtPath:strPath]) {
        NSError *error;
        [filemanager removeItemAtPath:strPath error:&error];
    }
    [filemanager release];
    filemanager = nil;

    //start unzip
    [za UnzipFileTo:strPath overWrite:YES];
    NSLog(@"path : %@",strPath);
}                   
[za release];
```