# How to download epub Format file from URL to Document Directory in Iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, nsurlconnection

I want to save an epub format file from url into App Document Directory.When I hit this url in browser it provides a downloading file where as when I send the request in NSURLConnection it provides me data, upon converting this data in to NSString return NULL.How to save this file with success.

My Code snippet is this :-

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 NSMutableString *str = [[NSMutableString alloc]
initWithFormat:@"http:// url", tagId];<br/>
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:str];
    NSLog(@"URL IS :%@",url);
    requestBook=[[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    NSLog(@"URL REQUEST :%@",url);
    receivedData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];<br/>     
     connectionDownloadBook =[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:requestBook delegate:self];
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
 if(connection==connectionDownloadBook) {
   NSLog(@"%@",connection);
        NSData *bookData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:requestBook returningResponse:nil error:&error];


    NSLog(@"%@",bookData);

   NSString *receivedDataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:bookData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"String %@",receivedDataString);
   [self savePDF:bookData];
}

}

- (void)savePDF:(NSData *)pdfContent
{
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask ,YES     );
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *finalPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myPdf.epub"];
NSLog(@"%@",finalPath);
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:finalPath];
[pdfContent writeToURL:url atomically:YES];

//    [aWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
}
```

> ```
> -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{
> NSLog(@"didReceiveData");
>  if (connection==connectionDownloadBook)
> {
>     [receivedData setLength:0];
> }
> }
>     -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{
> NSLog(@"didReceiveResponse");
> if (connection==connectionDownloadBook)
> {
>     [receivedData setLength:0];
> }
> }
>     -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
> NSLog(@"didFailWithError");
> //NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Connection failed: %@", [error description]]);
> }
> ```