# my own epub rendering application in iphone possible?

Tags: iphone, epub

I am required to make a app that renders epub format book in iPhone. Is it possible ? I know I can render PDFs using webView. how can I render epub formats ? is there any apple restrictions ?

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading ePub format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388467/reading-epub-format)

Comment: it's so lame to write duplicate of....  I constantly see new, better, correct answers when a question is asked multiple times.  First and foremost, it stimulates new interest.

Answer (score 0):

Its is possible I have been working on one for about a month now.

Take a look at:
http://groups.google.com/group/leaves-developers/browse_thread/thread/27e4bf5ff3c53113