# searching and highlighting a string in epub book in iphone or ipad

Tags: iphone, ipad

I am developing an epub ebook application, i am able to unzip and parse the epub and dispaly the TOC, text in a UIWebview with pagination.

I am able to search the particular string also and able to highlight the string also, but i am unable to navigate to that paricular page(where acutal string found and highlighted string page).

Could any one please guide me how we can I navigate to particular page where the actual found string is there?

Thanks in advance.

Shiva.

Comment: Once you found the search string using JavaScript you have to return the page number of that page. And you need to store that page number in the search item. So that you can navigate to that page easily.

Comment: Hi Satya, thank you for quick reply. Currently i am unable to get the searched string location.Once i know the location of searched string within xhtml file then as you said i can easily navigate to that particular page. any idea about how we can get the location of search string. and also the string may contain in many number of pages i need to get all those locations.

Answer (score 4):

You can find your requirement here

https://github.com/fedefrappi/AePubReader

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution for it, if any one required please refer to below code.

```
function getElementFromPoint(x,y) 
{ 
var str ="hello"; 
var i = 0; 
var j = 20; 
var x1 = parseInt(x)+j; 
alert("x"+x1); 
for( i = 0 ;i < 1024;i += 2) 
{ 
   var element = document.elementFromPoint(x1,i); 
   if(element.nodeName == "p" || element.nodeName == "h1" || element.nodeName == "h2" ||          element.nodeName == "h3") 
  { 
  str = element.innerText.trim(); 
  if(str.length <= 3) 
  continue; return str; 
  } 
 } 
return str; 
} 
getElementFromPoint(x,y);
```

Comment: What is x, y that are passed as parameters?