# Page-Based app load epub

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, epub, uipageviewcontroller

I am new to iphone app developing and need to display an epub file in an app that I am working on. I would like to use UIPageViewController as that allows paging ect. As of yet I have not been able to figure out how to load the content into a uiwebview and still get the paging function. If someone could point me to any sample code that would help me I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: check out the Adobe RMSDK: http://www.datalogics.com/products/rmsdk/

Answer (score 0):

You really can not use that, since you need ot use UIWebView.  I do not think that any other view offers enough of a head start to make it worth it not to use a UIWebView.

There was a lot of discussion about this found here:
[Reading ePub format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388467/reading-epub-format)

also see this:
[Best approch for creating ePub reader similar to iBook or Stanza application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4204379/best-approch-for-creating-epub-reader-similar-to-ibook-or-stanza-application)

Comment: I will make myself a little clearer. I have tried the code in the following link and everything is great, but now i can't figure out how to load epub content into the webview. If anyone can help me with this it would greatly help me. I am still quite new to ios programming. If nobody has anything on the epub I would like to try PDF as well. Here is the link to the code I followed. Thanks so much for the responses. http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_iOS_5_iPhone_UIPageViewController_Application