# page based load epub when changing font

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I am doing ebook reader app like as iBooks. I have succesfully read a .epub file. But my problem is:-

I have to add Font size increase and decrease and font changing functionality. I have to adjust pages When i increase and decrease font size . How can I split HTML string in pages ? .

You can see in both images . After changing font size the html string gets separated and the formatting is getting collapsed.

Thanks in advance

[image]   [image]

Comment: How are you loading the epub file? Is that a UIWebView or something else?

Comment: Using UIwebview. Basically i have html string of ebook . so i want to split that html string

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean when you say 'split that html string'?

Comment: @Joshua thankx for reply . i want to change font size  like as in iBooks app.

Comment: i have .epub file of ebook  and i have succesfully parse . now i want to calculate how many character that should be  fit in UIwebview according to  font size and font name .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I got answer .It is very simple .  In ios 7 you don't need to write javascript for pagination or any logic .

Just set UIWebview Property . Here is my code.

```
self.webView.paginationMode = UIWebPaginationModeLeftToRight;
self.webView.paginationBreakingMode = UIWebPaginationBreakingModePage;
self.webView.scrollView.delegate = self;
self.webView.scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
self.webView.scrollView.alwaysBounceHorizontal = YES;
self.webView.scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = NO;
self.webView.scrollView.bounces = YES;
```

Here is sample code a : https://github.com/kalpesh22m/Epub-Reader-With-Pegination

Answer (score 4):

Well, this is really a hard question...

I have an idea for a method that splits a HTML page into two parts: the first page, and the rest. You can then repeatedly call that method on the "rest" to get all pages.

1. Set $num_words = 100
2. Take the first $num_words words from the page => $first_page_html;
3. Put $first_page_html into UIWebView and "render" it (see note below).
4. Check height of UIWebView. Does it fit? If yes, return from algorithm.
5. If the words don't fit into the UIWebView, do $num_words--;
6. Otherwise, do $num_words++;
7. GOTO 2

This is a first algorithm that should work somehow. However, there are optimization opportunities and hidden problems:

You should probably do something like a binary search instead of a linear search. So $num_words should not be 100, 99, 98, 97, 96, ..., 62, but rather 100, 80, 60, 70, 65, 64, 63, 62. It would be even faster to ask the webview how much it is bigger or smaller than expected. I.e. if the webview is 30% too big in height, it means that you should reduce it by (1-1/(1+30%))=23%, so you should probably multiply the word-count by 0.77 in the first step.

When there are hard page-breaks in the document, your function should take that into account.

You get the height of the UIWebView by calling webView.scrollView.contentSize.height. I think you have to wait for the UIWebView to finish rendering before you can check the height though.

If you know a bit more about the structure of your HTML you may be able to use the `-stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` method from UIWebView to add individual words and see what happens. That way the webview doesn't have to re-render everything all the time.

Note: by "rendering" I mean calling `-loadHTMLString:baseURL:` and then waiting for the `-webViewDidFinishLoad:` delegate method to be called.

If performance is an issue it may be faster (for the device) to encode this algorithm in Javascript somehow, but I think that would be much harder.

Comment: Thanx for answer. can u give me snippiest code ?. and also want to know if book conatain 1000 pages then i think it will take more time to load.

Comment: with my algorithm, if you want to get the number of pages you would have to render all of them first. (you should save subpages to some caches directory, because 1000 UIWebView instances would probably crash the app.) The code will be complex with many edge and border cases that has to be worked out and tested. It would take me many hours to provide a decent algorithm made of Objective-C code. It's as hard for me as it is for you, so you have to do it on your own ;) And maybe there is a better way to solve this problem than my algorithm, but I thougt a non-perfect algo is better then no algo.

Comment: Nice algo, I do the same but I used paragraphs (`<p>` tag) instead of words this is less accurate but runs faster.

Comment: @sage444 have u tried for epub file that contain 1000 pages.

Comment: @sage444 can u give me some idea ? thanx

Comment: @Kalpesh yes, I tried it for large epub, on iPad4 this takes around 5 second, but content spited for few parts

Comment: @sage444 can u please give me some sample code ?.. or tell me  your algorithm and  procedure that you are used . I am totally new in java script . i dont have any knowledge about java script  . Please post as answer so i wll accept your answer. thanx

Comment: @Kalpesh I'm sorry, but I can't because is part of large project and hard mixed with other stuff. Try to code Michael algo is good to start then you will improve performance

Answer (score 1):

first to increase font size you need to give font size in em . before using em you need to give the body font-size:62.5% and for the elements inside div give font-size like 1.2em (which will act as 12px). so when you want to increase any Div's font-size you just have to increase font size of body by 10%.
And you don't need to calculate characters for adjusting pages and this is not good practice for if you are making responsive book. use column property off css, let css handle flow of your pages.
See below link for font size and **flowable html structure**

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hJ6Mj/4/)

```
<a href="http://jsfiddle.net/hJ6Mj/4/">Js Fiddle</a>
```

and also see "readium js for chrome". which will give you idea about how to render epub file on browser