# iPhone ePub Reader and eBook development

Tags: iphone, epub

I want to develop E-Book application in iphone by using ePub format with page turn animation. How can i used ePub format in iphone?I have to also break ePub page dynamically for page turn animation like Stanza.  If anybody worked on ePub ebook app please guide me how to start.I wasted too many days in research. :-(

Comment: wasted??? i think u have gained a lot during research.

Comment: if i had gained then why i am asking you here...?

Comment: Duplicate of a bazillion other questions like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388467/reading-epub-format