# How to parse epub file content after unzipping it

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, epub

I am developing an Ebook for iPhone that loads ePUB file. I have unzipped the epub file. Now I want to view the content in the unzipped epub file. how would I proceed from here?

Comment: Is it a (x)html epub or a docbook epub(uncommon)?

Comment: @CodeInChaos - I think you mean DTBook not Docbook

Answer (score 1):

Have a read of the ePUB file format (from wikipedia - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EPUB)

This points out the files that are the starting points of the book i.e. the container.xml file will tell you where the main opf files are etc.

Answer (score 0):

ePub files include HTML files, have you tried viewing them in UIWebView, or creating a parser?

Comment: But, there is a file called container.xml and some other files like css, ncx, opf....which file do I need to parse? I am a bit confused..

Comment: There should be multiple files with the same file name, numbered sequentially. Those files will hold the main content.

Comment: Thanks. I didnt see the files with same file name. These are the files I have when I excract ePUB file. http://screencast.com/t/G2Iu3RDv5

Comment: That doesnt look like a complete ePub. This is what a complete ePub file's contents should look like: http://snapplr.com/pvfz

Comment: Hi, is it enough id I able to view content of HTML file?..no need of working with container.xml?

Comment: You don't seem to have an understanding of the ePub format. I would read more on it to getnmore familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at this thread [Reading ePub format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388467/reading-epub-format) which describes detail steps(From Euan) and [sample project](http://ideveloperworld.blogspot.in/2011/02/epub-reader.html) (From Sreelal).