# how to parse XML file from a epub file

Tags: objective-c, xml, xcode, ios4, epub

how to parse the XML file which has a content like this..

http://screencast.com/t/tQ4YtnfZ

I am developing an ebook reader app that loads epub file...

how can I parse content.opf inside the XML file?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use unzip and xml parser to do this.

Looks like following thread may be of your help
[link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388467/reading-epub-format)