# iPhone - Convert ePub file to iphone app

Tags: iphone, epub

Can some one tell me whether any control or framework is there that will show epub files as an iphone app?

```
NSString* filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"LittleBoPeep-ANurseryRhymePictureBook" ofType:@"epub"];
UIWebView* wv = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
[self.view addSubview:wv];
[wv loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]]];
```

Comment: You want to show ePub files an an App ???

Comment: Yes, I want to show epub files as an app.

Answer (score 2):

ePub files basically use HTML files (among others) to compile what you would see in iBooks. You can unzip the ePub file and display the HTML files in a UIWebView, or any other way you decide to go about it.

Comment: thank you very much. i never came across any file which is in epub format. i'll study more on it.

Comment: I'm afraid that webview is not showing epub files.... i updated my description with the code that i'm using... have a look at it.

Comment: You need to unzip it. An epub is actually a zip file containing multiple HTML files and images.

Comment: There's a mini-walkthrough here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388467/reading-epub-format/2034410#2034410