# How to display epub file in UIWebview

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reading ePub format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388467/reading-epub-format)

I want to show my `.epub` file in iPhone application.

Answer (score 1):

The answer can be found over here

[Reading ePub format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388467/reading-epub-format)