# ePub reader shows ePub files content's font sometimes Bold sometimes regular

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have made one application in which I implemented ePub reader which unzips file and parses xml file. I have adopted method of this question on S.O. [Reading ePub format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388467/reading-epub-format) .

The code was working fine till today before I replaced **.ePub** files with client's updated files. After replacing .ePub files I ran application on simulator and I was shocked as ePub reader shows all file's content in **BOLD** format randomly, I mean assuming there are **5** .ePub files in application sometimes it shows file 2,3 content in **BOLD** sometimes file 1,4,5 content in **BOLD**. I could not figure out the problem so I replaced those files with older ones and problem disappeared..

Following the apple guidelines  http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4168. I recommended client to use Pages '09 to export ePub files. So is it the problem with coversion using Pages '09? because I have opened all .ePub files in stanza and calibre and contents were **not in BOLD format.** So I can't figure out wether its a conversion problem or coding problem.

Code I used for reading ePub files(Maybe it will help): http://pastebin.com/dY4CFetU

Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite probable from your description that the problem resides in the provided ePub files. Try validating the ePub with an ePub validator, like [this one](http://threepress.org/document/epub-validate). You should then be able to find the mistake in the xml.