# Opening a epub file on a UIWebView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, epub

Xcode Open File (epub) with xcode programming - NOT OPENING (O just see a little white block on upper right)

I have also added epub file in project, I am using following below code to open it in viewdidload method.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSString *filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"MyEpub" ofType:@"epub"];
    UIWebView *wv = [[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    [self.view addSubview:wv];
    [wv loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath]]];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading ePub format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388467/reading-epub-format)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you won't be able to open an ePub file in a `UIWebView`, because it's not a supported format.

Apple provide a list of supported formats here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1630/_index.html

You'll need to use the link Jano provided above to decompress, parse, and open up the file.