# How to play video from epub file?

Tags: ios

i want to create an epub reader with feature like play video and audio from my iphone app.
One more thing i would like to say that it will not a web based applicaton.
i mean to say that i dont want to use uiwebview.
please any body help me thanx in adv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The epub format is wrapped as a zip file (you can just unzip it). There was a lot of discussion about it in this thread:

- [Reading ePub format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388467/reading-epub-format)

So you can just add the audio/video in the zip and then runnit locally using MPMoviePlayer. If you want to be able to actually show the book you must re-implement a web engine, as epub books uses HTML to diagram. So, as far as I know, the UIWebView is the easiest way to go.

Answer (score 3):

EPUB3 supports  tag, http://idpf.org/epub/30/spec/epub30-overview.html#sec-multimedia

So you can embed video like this:

```
<video id="my_video_1" width="720" height="365" preload="auto" controls="true">
<source src="../Misc/my_video_1.m4v" />
</video>
```

And, H.264 or VP8 video codecs are recoomended.
http://idpf.org/epub/30/spec/epub30-publications.html#note-video-codecs

Comment: my question is regarding developing iphone app not epub