# e-pub reader for phonegap

Tags: cordova, epub

I am trying to develop an phonegap application to read ePub files.I have no idea about how to read this file format.please help me by providing links.

Answer (score 3):

Looking into epub - google tells me that its part of the Open eBook format . 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_eBook

Using the Phonegap API you can read files - http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#File

So the rest is up to you. Investigate the how the file is stored and then workout how to read it using the API. There doesn't seem to be much in the way using phonegap to read it.

I would say it would be quite challenging .

Answer (score 0):

Also take a look at this other SO post on the epub format: [Reading ePub format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388467/reading-epub-format?rq=1). Note that while some of the advice given is specific to iPhone development / objective-C, there's also quite a bit of info on the epub format itself.