# EPub File Read on Phonegap?

Tags: cordova, epub

I need to know about to read epub file content to book format. I have one epub file i.e "content.epub".

content.epub contains 3 pages text.

How i can read this epub file using phonegap.I am new to phonegap.Can you please suggest me what to do for this?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple places to look:

- This SO post explains some of the internals of the epub format: [Reading ePub format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388467/reading-epub-format?rq=1). Some of the information is specific to Objective-C (so it won't be usable to you), but at least you can get a sense of what the epub format looks like.
- Depending on where you're getting the .epub files from, you'll either need to download them or use the cordova-plugin-file to read them from the local device. The cordova-plugin-file has really poor documentation, but there are a few other resources out there if you need more help:

  - Raymond Camden has a few examples on his blog like this one: http://www.raymondcamden.com/2014/07/01/Cordova-Sample-Check-for-a-file-and-download-if-it-isnt-there. It's worth looking at what he's done.
  - For what it's worth, I also put up some code on SO to show how to browse through the device and collect the available files: [How to get documents in an android directory that PhoneGap will see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29678186/how-to-get-documents-in-an-android-directory-that-phonegap-will-see).