# Recursively Read all files and folder structure using Cordova

Tags: angularjs, cordova, phonegap-plugins, ngcordova

IS there any way to read the files and folder   structure recursively starting from root.
The scope here is to scan all the files present in the directory along with there directory ,sub-directory using cordova

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29905718/346550. This is using the cordova file plugin.

Answer (score 0):

```
scan : function(url,fileType,callback)
        {
             var fileTypeCollection = [];
             var defer = $q.defer();


                url.forEach(function(element, index) 
                {
                //requestLocalFileSystemURL
                log(element);
                window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(element,onRequestFileSystem, fail);


                log("Ends resolve");
                });


            function onRequestFileSystem(fileSystem) 
            {
                var directoryReader = fileSystem.createReader();
                directoryReader.readEntries(onReadEntries,fail);
            } /*onRequestFile Ends*/

            function onReadEntries(entries) 
            {


                if(entries.length==0)
                {
                     log("Entries Length....Resolving");
                     defer.resolve(fileTypeCollection);
                }
                else
                {   
                    entries.forEach( function(element, index) 
                    {

                        if (element.isDirectory === true) 
                        {
                        // Recursive -- call back into this subdirectory

                         onRequestFileSystem(element);
                        } 

                        if(element.isFile == true) 
                        {

                                fileType.forEach(function(type)
                                {
                                    if(element.name.indexOf(type) != -1)
                                    {
                                        fileTypeCollection.push(element);
                                    }
                                }); 
                        } /*is File ENds*/
                    });  /*Entries For Each Ends*/
                }   

            }  /*OnRead Ends*/

            function fail(resp)
            {
                log(resp);
                defer.reject();
            }  /*Fail Ends*/

        return defer.promise;

    }  //Scan Function Ends
```

Answer (score 0):

have a look.This plugin can scan files based on filetype

```
https://github.com/siddmegadeth/Cordova-Media-Scanner
```