# Can't get access to the root directory phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

Currently I am working a project where I have to get access to the Music directory which can be found in the Root. I am trying to get the directory with the Phonegap/Cordova plugin: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file

I tried many things and I did research on Google but couldn't find anything good..
Here is my code:

```
/* THIS IS PLACED IN THE onDeviceReady FUNCTION! */        
window.requestFileSystem(window.TEMPORARY, 1024*1024, onFileSystemSuccess, function(e) { alert("Something went wrong.."); });
alert( "5" );
/*************************************************/

    function onFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
        alert("6"); // just for testing
        fileSystem.root.getDirectory("Music", {}, getDirSuccess, function(e) { alert("Doesn't work"); } );
    }

    function getDirSuccess(dirEntry) {
        alert("7");
        var directoryReader = dirEntry.createReader();
        directoryReader.readEntries(readerSuccess,fail);
    }
```

Comment: can you give me screenshot of the file location you want to open ?

Comment: @Microsmsm http://prntscr.com/a790i5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm... you might want to try `window.resolveLocalFilesystemURL()` instead of `window.requestFilesystem()` if you're looking to read the filesystem.

I've got a sample routine that iterates through a bunch of directories here: [How to get documents in an android directory that PhoneGap will see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29678186/how-to-get-documents-in-an-android-directory-that-phonegap-will-see/29905718#29905718). It might help narrow your search.

Comment: I will take a look at this, Thank you.

Comment: I fixed it by using windows.resolveLocalFileSystemURL() instead of window.requestFilesystem().

Answer (score 0):

Try the following path :

```
/android_asset/www/song.mp3
```

Comment: I am trying to access the music directory of Android, not mine WWW folder