# Know when to use cordova.file.externalRootDirectory in Android

Tags: android, file, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

`cordova.file.externalRootDirectory` will always exist and the app will think that there is an SD card even when there isn't an SD card. So in turn, files downloaded to `cordova.file.externalRootDirectory` won't exist. How can I be sure when to use `cordova.file.externalRootDirectory` in Android? If there is no SD card for my files to successfully be downloaded into, I want to use the `cordova.file.dataDirectory`. Is there a work-around for this?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you've already found an answer for this -- if you haven't, you can take a look at [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29905718/346550). The code there iterates through a list of `cordova.file.<xxx>` items, listing the filenames (and recursing into subdirectories). If you are planning on listing directory contents, you could do something similar for just `cordova.file.externalRootDirectory` and `cordova.file.datadirectory`.

However, if you are testing for the existence of an SD card -- say to write to it -- you would just need check to see if there are any entries for `cordova.file.externalRootDirectory` (just check to see if entries.length > 0). If there are any, you could assume that there is an SD card installed.