# Create FileChooser for android phone

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app

I am creating a hybrid app using cordova version 6.3 . On Android, I would like to the user to select a file from their device. Basically, i want a file chooser to show up and then the user select a file that is store on the android phone.

The current input type="file" does not work. It did work with a different version of SDK(19) and cordova

Can you give me some hint or some some  sample code showing how I can implement this feature

Comment: there are lot of plugins available.. https://github.com/MaginSoft/MFileChooser / https://github.com/don/cordova-filechooser will work

Comment: The MfileChooser does not return a file and  don/cordova-filechooser does not have an option to pick from the local android device...  Did you get any of them to work?

Comment: Try this https://github.com/tigoe/BeginningNFC/tree/master/FileSender/plugins/com.megster.cordova.FileChooser  Its working for me.

Comment: @Navneeth , I tried the plugins,it shows the chooser and files but it does not return the file .. I am using cordova 6.3, and sdk 23. What version did you use in your implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<input type="file">` element also doesn't work as you'd expect in iOS -- it displays a list of photos IIRC.

I ended up writing my own routine to iterate through the phone's directories (using the plugin `cordova-plugin-file`) and gather the files -- see https://stackoverflow.com/a/29905718/346550. After getting the list, I display the entries in an unordered list of hyperlinks. You could really display the file results however you wanted, though.

Comment: I used the code in link  but I do not see the files for  download folder on android.  How do you get this information . thanks

Comment: On the SD card, it's a subdirectory of `cordova.file.externalRootDirectory`. I'm not sure where it resides on the device itself (or if it's even accessible). That's probably another SO question.
Here's some more details about the filesystem layouts -- they vary from platform to platform: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/#file-system-layouts

Comment: I should add: in Android > 5, you also need runtime permissions to see some files/directories. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47143656/no-fileentry-results-returned-on-android-6