# List the files that are stored in the download folder on an Android device

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

How do you retrieve the list of files that are stored in the download folder on android phone.

I have  an cordova based app that contains a button. When it is press, I would like to show the user a list a files in their download folder and let them select one..

I have the "cordova-plugin-file" installed  and I tried accessing the information from the following folders"

```
var localURLs    = [
cordova.file.dataDirectory,
cordova.file.documentsDirectory,
cordova.file.externalApplicationStorageDirectory,
cordova.file.externalCacheDirectory,
cordova.file.externalRootDirectory,
cordova.file.externalDataDirectory,
cordova.file.sharedDirectory,
cordova.file.syncedDataDirectory
```

];

and the code from [How to get documents in an android directory that PhoneGap will see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29678186/how-to-get-documents-in-an-android-directory-that-phonegap-will-see/29905718#29905718)

However, none of the folders return the files stored in the download folder on the device.

Is there another method to access this information..

Thanks