# Cannot create directory with Cordova file plugin

Tags: android, android-studio, cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-plugin-file

I use the below code in order to create Folder_Name directory in android cordova project with no luck

```
   writeFile();

function writeFile() {
    console.log(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory);
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory, function(fileSystem){
        var entry = "";
            entry = fileSystem;
       console.log(entry);
        entry.getDirectory("Folder_Name", {
            create: true
        }, onGetDirectorySuccess, onGetDirectoryFail);
    }, onError);
}

function onError(e) {
    alert("onError");
};

function onGetDirectoryFail(dir) {
    console.log("directory does not created!!!!!");
};

function onGetDirectorySuccess(dir) {
    console.log("directory created.");
};
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: On an Android 10 or 11 device you normally cannot create directories in root of external storage.

Comment: So I have to add filesystem/something ??

Comment: I expected you to tell wich Android version tried.

Comment: I tried it in android 10

Comment: Which permissions did you ask already?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: Is that all? No runtime permissons?

Comment: no runtime permissions

Comment: Then you should first start with them.

Comment: how to add them in cordova project. Please point a tutorial

Comment: I dont know. I dont use Cordova.

Comment: @kosbou - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/29905718/346550 (the Feb 2018 edit part).